# Quotient groups and dihedral groups

Tags: group-theory

I came across a question asking for me to find all the possible quotient groups for the dihedral group $D_6$. How must I go about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that your definition of $D_6$ is
$$D_6=\{1,r,r^2,s,sr,sr^2\}$$
where $r^3=s^2=rsrs=1$.
A quotient set $D_6/N$ is a group if and only if $N\lhd D_6$. Hence, we want to find all normal subgroups of $D_6$. We always have the trivial ones
$$D_6/D_6\cong\{1\}$$
and
$$D_6/\{1\}\cong D_6.$$
The subgroup $\langle r\rangle = \langle r^2\rangle= \{1,r,r^2\}$ is of index $2$ and thus normal. So
$$D_6/\langle r\rangle$$
is a quotient group also. If $N\lhd D_6$ is a different normal subgroup, then $|N|=2$, so either $N=\langle s \rangle$, $N=\langle sr\rangle$ or $N=\langle sr^2\rangle$. But none of them are normal. For example $\langle s \rangle$ is not normal since $(sr)s(sr)^{-1}=sr^2\notin\langle s \rangle$. Hence, the only non-trivial quotient group is
$$D_6/\langle r\rangle\cong\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$$

Comment: How can we just assume $D_6$?

Comment: I meant: "I assume that your definition of $D_6$ is the following..." I will clarify.