# Find all Quotient (or Factor) Groups of $D_4$ (Dihedral Group of order $8$)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, dihedral-groups, quotient-group

I need to be able to find all of the quotient groups for dihedral group 4 with

$D_4 = \{ e,R,R^2,R^3,V,H,D,D'\}$.

I know I have to start by finding the normal subgroups, which are

$\{e,R^2\}$
$\{e,R,R^2,R^3\}$
$\{e,R^2,V,H\}$
$\{e,R^2,D,D'\}$.

Then I need to find the sets defined by
$G/H=\{ aH : a \in G\}$ with operation $aH  bH = abH$.

I am stuck here; could someone please show me how to find all of the factor groups for D4?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  If the normal subgroup has order four, then the quotient has order two, and there's only one group of order two up to isomorphism

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! What subgroups is that explicitly?

Comment: cyclic group of order $2$

Comment: I guess you want me to say, for example, the quotient group $D_4/${$e,R,R^2,R^3$} has two elements:  $\{e,R,R^2,R^3$} and {$V,H,D,D'$}

Comment: Thanks for another speedy reply. What about the other quotient groups for each of the other normal subgroups?

Comment: The identity element of the quotient group is the set of elements of the normal subgroup

Comment: Here is [the answer for the order 6 dihedral group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/579670/quotient-groups-and-dihedral-groups?rq=1). The exact same principles apply to the order 8 dihedral group of your question.

Comment: though there is a non-trivial subgroup  of index not $2$ for the order $8$ group

Comment: See  https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2729206/403337.

Answer (score 1):

The identity element of the quotient group is the coset which has elements of the normal subgroup.  For example $D_4/\{e,R,R^2,R^3\}$ has identity element $\{e,R,R^2,R^3\}$. If the group has order $8$ and the normal subgroup has order $4$, then the order of the quotient group is $2$, so there is only one other element of the quotient group besides the identity -- it's the coset which comes from the group elements not in the normal subgroup.

If the normal subgroup has order $2$, then the quotient subgroup has order $4$.  I.e., $D_4/\{e,R^2\}$ has identity $\{e,R^2\}$ and its three cosets $\{R,R^3\}, \{V,H\},$ and $\{D,D'\}.$

It should be noted that you omitted the trivial normal subgroups $\{e\}$ and $D_4.$

Comment: So would D4/ {e,R2,V,H} also be {e,R2,V,H} and {e, R, R2, R3}? I think all the order 2 quotient groups are isomorphic

Comment: No, {$e,R^2$,V,H} and {$R,R^3,$ D,D'}; cosets are disjoint; yes, all order 2 groups are isomorphic (per my first comment to your question)

Comment: I think I get it now. So would D4/ {e,R2,D,D'} be {e,R2,D,D'} and {R,R3,V,H}? I am looking at the Cayley table to deduce this

Comment: It would be that

Comment: I should have mentioned in my answer that the quotient group of order $2$ is isomorphic to the cyclic (or any) group of order $2$, and the quotient group of order $4$ is isomorphic to the Klein four group, in which all three non-identity elements have order $2$, which is not isomorphic to the cyclic group of order $4$